# What animal is this track from?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Last week I noticed this odd track made of "squiggly triangle footprints" on the outside surface of a dirty skylight in [my home in the northern Netherlands](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Weidum/@53.1425023,5.7265206,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c8fbbe68ee1199:0x755aa83a22b18233!8m2!3d53.1460496!4d5.7438755), and I found it odd that I can't imagine what kind of animal this track would have come from. I assume it's animal since the movement seems very intentional and the triangle shapes are periodic, rather than being a continuous smudge that might be caused by a tiny leaf blown in the wind for example. Each tiny triangular "footprint" is around 3mm wide. Any pointers on how to identify what caused this track?

[image]

Comment: My guess is a rocking and rolling pinecone.

Comment: any kind of close up would be a huge help, I can't see any detail.

Comment: Yeah I thought of a pinecone-like object being blown around, but note that it appears to all be a single track which moves up and down and around in a very consistent pattern, no skips. Also note that this is a pretty steep skylight; I wouldn't expect even a very fortuitous wind to keep a roundish object in place long enough to do such an intricate pattern. @John sorry that's the only image I grabbed before I washed the offending window :-) but a reasonable amount of detail is visible if you zoom in.

Comment: @TopherHunt Is there a coniferous plant above the window? Have you tried taking one of the cones and reproducing the pattern? Perhaps if the cone is not roundish, but more cylindrical or cone-like shaped, this could explain the left-to-right wiggly pattern of its descent ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Snail feeding.

It is really obvious if you have seen it before. It is the track left by a feeding snail.

Here is the grazing pattern of the common snail.

[image]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Land_Snail_radula_tracks.jpg

https://alexhyde.photoshelter.com/image/I0000oboo93ZzSEI

Comment: YES thank you. And that fits because Friesland is teeming with snails and slugs. Allegedly they don't have many predators here.